# Engine Yard rollback a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations, engineyard

I deployed a new feature to Engine Yard that had migrations.  Of course I passed the migration flag and it worked successfully.  But then I decided to take the feature out.

Note: These migrations removed some columns

I then rolled back on github and deployed again, but now I'm getting a postgres error that a column doesn't exist (this is a column removed in the migration from before)

How do you rollback migrations on Engine Yard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that when you ssh into your engineyard app you can go to the current deploy's directory and run `bundle exec rake ...` thus you can run probably run `bundle exec rake db:rollback`

Answer (score 0):

TMP,

While there is a `rollback` command built into the `engineyard` gem, it would be better to just deploy with a new migration that effectively adds the columns back in or update the code to not use the missing columns.

Evan

Comment: that seems inefficient though.  i've seen things about the rollback command but that doesn't handle it.  it's odd you can't just rollback migrations